# Need help on Proof Question involving relatively prime and gcd

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let a and n be two natural numbers.

Prove that if $\gcd(a,n)=1$, there exists a unique natural number $b < n$ such that $ab \equiv  1 \pmod n$

Prove $\exists b \in  \mathbb N\Big( (b < n) \land (ab \equiv 1 \pmod n)\Big)$

Comment: Is ≡n supposed to mean "equivalent, mod n"? I.e. Are you asking that if a and n are relatively prime, there exists a unique natural number $b\lt n$ such that $ab \equiv 1\pmod n$?

Comment: yes I am asking that exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $b, c \in \Bbb N$ such that $ab \equiv ac \equiv 1[n]$

Then $bac \equiv b \equiv c[n]$ thus $b\equiv c[n]$ and you have unicity.

If $\gcd(a, n) = 1$, you have a Bézout identity, ie there exists $u, v \in \Bbb Z$ such that $au + nv = 1$. You then have $au \equiv 1[n]$. Therefore you have existence.

Comment: what does 1[n] mean?

Comment: and also isnt it basically asking to prove Bézout identity?

Comment: I'm guessing it means $1 \pmod n$.

Comment: Yes, $[n]$ means "mod n" here

Comment: so is it basically asking to prove the identity?

Comment: I don't know, this is your question is it not ?

Comment: it is but im unclear on how Mr.books did his answer? im not sure how this can use Bezout's identity, I think we have to prove it instead. Im not sure though

Comment: How was the gcd defined to you ?

Comment: We say that two natural numbers are relatively prime if their greatest common divisor (gcd) is equal to 1. For example, 9 and 14 are relatively prime but 12 and 15 are not (since gcd(12, 15) = 3)